# Zend Framework: Give result back

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, frameworks

I will return a result of a MySQL Query.
But he's return the MySQL Query.

```
public function getLatestId() {
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $db->getConnection();
        $result = $db->select()->from("raw_data", array(new Zend_Db_Expr("MAX(id) AS locationname")));
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` has the select query statement not the result you need to fetch the result. try following lines:

```
$result = $db->select()->from("raw_data", array(new Zend_Db_Expr("MAX(id) AS locationname")));
$row = $this->fetchRow($result);
return $row->toArray();
```

I am using following function to get the max id as maxItemNumber

```
function getLatestId(){
    $select = $this->select()
        ->from('raw_data', array(new Zend_Db_Expr("MAX(id) AS maxItemNumber")));

    $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
    if(!$row){
        return 0;
    }

    $row = $rows->toArray();
    return $row['maxItemNumber'];
}
```

If you want to get the lastInsertedID immediately after insert then use return with insert

```
return $this->insert($data);
```

Comment: are you using DbTable class that extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract ?

Comment: Yes. My class: `class Application_Model_Mysqldata extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    public function getLatestId() {
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $db->getConnection();
        $result = $db->select()->from("data_raw", array(new Zend_Db_Expr("MAX(id) AS Locationname")));
    }

}`

Comment: check the function I have edited. If you get the error then show here

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are building and next returning query ... but not execute this query.
Harish Singh show this explicite.